# Install python 2.6 in a sandbox/virt-env

Tags: python, virtualenv, sandbox

I have python 2.7 running on ubuntu 14.04. and, I need to set up `py2.6` in a sandbox environment. I tried using the command, virtualenv as

```
virtualenv /path/to/sandbox --no-site-packages
```

But, it copies `/usr/bin/python2.7` binary file into the sandbox's bin folder.

Using `pythonbrew` also didn't work, as it throws compilation errors almost always.

How to create a sandbox environment and install `python2.6` binary in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualenv won't really install a new python version from scratch, but rather copy one of the versions installed on your system. That's why you first need to get a python2.6 binary for Ubuntu 14.04. It seems they don't officially support python2.6 anymore, so either you manually download and install it from http://python.org or use a ppa like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.6
```

afterwards you can tell virtualenv to use python2.6 like this:

```
virtualenv -p python2.6 --no-site-packages /path/to/sandbox
```

Comment: thanks, Jorn.. it works.. but this command -- `sudo apt-cache update` didn't work. and i used `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: sorry, was a copy paste error from `apt-cache search` i think... corrected.